# Old version of Signal persists after update

Tags: signal

Upon installing the latest version of Signal (6.16.0) the old and in-operable version (5.54.0) persists. Normally with other applications, the new version is installed and the old version is automatically removed.The old version that was installed may have been for Xenial, a different branch of Linux.

How do I go about removing the old version?
Please, when answering, give clear procedural instruction as to commands.

My desktop computer OS is: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

I greatly appreciate all help on this problem.

UPDATE: I have reached out to Signal on this problem. They suggested that I enter the following commands, which did not work:-(
Linux:

- Use apt-get remove signal-desktop
- Delete ~/.config/Signal
  I have uninstalled the latest version of Signal (6.16.0) with the idea that it might remove both versions, but no... the old version remains there and is inoperable.
- If I remember correctly I originally installed Signal from: signal.org/download/#
- In answer to Whereis signal: new@localhost:~$ whereis signal signal: /usr/share/man/man7/signal.7.gz /usr/share/man/man2/signal.2.gz

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1467552/edit) to show the complete output of `whereis signal`

Comment: How did you install these programs in the first place?

Comment: If I remember correctly I originally installed Signal from: https://signal.org/download/#

Comment: I am clueless about this but I put in whereis signal in there terminal and this is the response: new@localhost:~$ whereis signal
signal: /usr/share/man/man7/signal.7.gz /usr/share/man/man2/signal.2.gz I hope this is what you are looking for...

Comment: If you followed the instructions at the link you gave from signal.org to install the software, what they told you to do "sudo apt remove signal-desktop" is the correct answer.  The crux of this question may be, how did you install the old version? And how do you know it still "persists" - in other words, what are the symptoms? It's not sufficient to say things "don't work". Edit your question and give *specifics* - error messages, the exact commands you typed in, etc. For example, if you just typed in `apt-get remove signal-desktop`, that won't work. You have to use sudo. Details matter here!

Comment: Ah-ha! "You have to use sudo" The email from Signal Support

Comment: Ah-ha! "sudo"! Issue resolved! Signal Support's generic reply (no mention of sudo) Hi,
To uninstall and remove all data (including message history) from the Signal Desktop app, follow steps for your computer OS below.
Mac OSX:
- Delete the Signal.app file from the /Application or ~/Application directory
- Delete local data from ~/Library/Application Support/Signal
 Windows:
- Select 'Uninstall Signal.exe' in C:\Users<Your Name>\AppData\Local\Programs\signal-desktop
- Delete C:\Users<YourName>\AppData\Roaming\Signal
 Linux:
- Use apt-get remove signal-desktop
- Delete ~/.config/Signal